# for line in json object returns one character per line

Tags: python

Whenever I execute this code...

```
import json, urrlib2
res = urrlib2.urlopen('http://website.com/data.json')
data = json.load(res)
for line in json.dumps(data["specific"]["data"], sort_keys=True, indent=0):
    print line
```

Every character is printed in a new line. I am using python2.7 and I have literally no idea, what is going wrong. It should not do that, because when I print the data before the for line statement, I get a nicely formatted list of stuff.

Comment: `json.dumps` creates a string. When you iterate over a string, you do so by character. Why are you using `.dumps`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because dump always throws the error that it needs at least 2 arguments - despite the fact that I am giving it more than two. Supposedly it works the same as dumps, or am I reading the doc wrong?

Comment: `json.dumps(obj, ...)` creates a formatted string; `json.dump(obj, f, ...)` will write the string to a file (the second **positional** argument). What are you trying to achieve? If you just want to iterate over the content, use `for line in data['specific']['data']:`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh...yeah that makes sense. Thank you very much, I was breaking my head over that.

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps(obj)` will turn the `obj` into a formatted string (which can be written out to a file using `json.dump(obj, file)`. When you iterate over a string, you iterate over its characters:

```
>>> for line in "abc":
    print(line)


a
b
c
```

Instead, I think you want to iterate over the *content of the object*, for example:

```
for line in data["specific"]["data"]:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data using read:

```
data = res.read()
data = json.load(data)
```